# Find elements $x,y$ where $x\ne \pm1$ and $y\ne \pm 1$ in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ satisfying $xy=19$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Find elements $x,y$ where $x\ne \pm1$ and $y\ne \pm 1$ in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ satisfying $xy=19$.

I'm lost as to what to do. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps, $x = \frac{19}{5}$ and $y = 5$?

Comment: What do elements of this field look like?  When you multiply those elements what is the resulting element look like?  Try simple cases if you are stuck but try something first....

Comment: Trivial in the field. In the ring of integers of this field,  use $8+3\sqrt{5}$ and its conjugate.

Comment: Are you being asked to find all the elements in the ring of integers of the field?

Comment: no, not all elements

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=a+b\sqrt{5}$, $y=c+d\sqrt{5}$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Then
$$(a+b\sqrt{5})(c+d\sqrt{5})=19,$$
then
$$ac+5bd=19,$$
$$ad+bc=0.$$

There are $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ that are solutions:

$(a,b,c,d)=(1,2,-1,2)$, $(a,b,c,d)=(8,3,8,-3)$.

So,

examples:

$$x=1+2\sqrt{5}, y=-1+2\sqrt{5};$$
$$x=8+3\sqrt{5}, y=8-3\sqrt{5}.$$

---

And other kind of examples:

$x=(2+\sqrt{5}, y=19(-2+\sqrt{5})$;
$x=(38+17\sqrt{5}, y=19(-38+\sqrt{17})$.

These examples are closely related to integer/rational solutions of eq.
$$a^2-5b^2=\pm 19,$$
$$a^2-5b^2=\pm 1.$$

Comment: How did you come up with $(a,b,c,d)=(1,2,-1,2)$? Through inspection?

Comment: @1233dfv, yes, with the help of PC..